# How to create Bootstrap 'input-group-text' in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am in need to create Bootstrap input-group-text look a like using angular material. Here is how it should look
[image]

currently default implementation of Angular material only allow to add suffix but doesn't let style them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Material Design UI suite is very opinionated. You'll have to do a lot of style overrides to achieve what you're trying to do.

But to answer your question though, you need to inspect the element and override the rules in your main CSS file (not in your component). 
Try adding to your input element something like:

```
 <mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Recipient's username</mat-label>
   <input matInput>
   <p matSuffix>@example.com</p>
 </mat-form-field>
```

and then in your main `styles.css`:

```
.mat-form-field-suffix {
  background: lightgray;
  /* rest of your styles */
}
```

You may need to add more classes depending on the style rule specificity.
You'll have to add the rest of the styles though.